# How can I properly swap variables between a setTimeout and a promise

Tags: javascript

I have a promise function and I am assigning a variable in that function. On completion of the promise, I wanna reassign that variable. It only assigns at the beginning but doesn't reassign when the promise is done. I attached a setTimeOut function to make sure that my initial assignment only lasts for 300 ms.

```
transition = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Cursor2.newDiagonal = this.diagonalWindow()
      setTimeout(() => {
       
        resolve
      }, 300)
     
      
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("get in")
      Cursor2.newDiagonal = this.diagonalWindow() / 9
    })
  }
```

On page load, my function is called and it assigned the Cursor2.newDiagonal to this.diagonalWindow and completely remains there. What I want to do is on page load, Cursor2.newDiagonal should be assigned to this.diagonalWindow for a period of 300 ms and then reassigned back to this.diagonalWindow() / 9.

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: The `resolve` value is a *function*, and you have to call it: `resolve();`

Comment: @Pointy I just added this and it skips directly to the then function without assigning the first variable for 30 seconds.

Comment: 300ms is not a very long time. Try increasing that to 3000 and see if you notice the timer.

Comment: @Pointy with 3000 it does set the first variable but gets stuck on that and doesn't reset the variable in the then function.